# Azure + Appium + C# : While creating azure pipeline I am getting error "You are not authorized to access https://dss-hps.visualstudio.com."

Tags: c#, appium, mobile-automation, azure-devops, cicd

I am trying to create Azure pipeline to integrate automation. Observed error :

> **You are not authorized to access https://dss-hps.visualstudio.com.**

Please let me know if anyone face/fix this issue. Refer screenshot for more clarity

[image]

Comment: Did you try again after about 30 minutes? Azure takes time to allocate resources. Otherwise the error you posted simply reads that your access token didn't match what Azure was expecting for the server URL.

Comment: yes - I tried not specifically after 30 min but approx 3-4 hrs continuously. Exactly and just for access token :(

Pls share if you fix this at your end